# Is there a default button for showing the current location in GMSMapView sdk

Tags: ios, google-maps

I am adding a custom button and adding the action

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D target=CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(currentLocation.coordinate.latitude,currentLocation.coordinate.longitude);
     [mapView_ animateToLocation:target];
```

for moving the map to current location.Is there a default button in the sdk ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes there is a default button to show current location of map. It will be only visible when you set `myLocationEnable` in the API.

From the documentation

[Google Map SDK for iOS](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/map#my_location)

> By default, no location data is shown on the map. You may enable the blue "My Location" dot and compass direction by setting myLocationEnabled on GMSMapView.

```
mapView_.myLocationEnabled = YES;
```

> Enabling this feature will also provide the user's current location through the myLocation property. This property may not be immediately available - for example, if the user is prompted by iOS to allow access to this data. It will be nil in this case.

```
NSLog(@"User's location: %@", mapView_.myLocation);
```

Comment: Might also need to do this:
mapView.settings.myLocationButton = true